# how to create floatingActionButton like this and hide items?

Tags: android

[image]

Messenger floating action button

Comment: Github is you friend. And look for projects called FloatingActionButton. Try searching before posting such a question.

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Here the example,this link can help yours.
https://github.com/wangjiegulu/RapidFloatingActionButton